# Link login and register links to wordpress registration

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I am using a short code for bbpress registration which is: [bbp-login]

What I have done is that I added Lost Password | Register links.

I need to add a functions to these URL's to work in the same way as wp-login.php.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're looking at exactly. But maybe BBPress adds a class to `body` like `logged-in` or something similar?

If so, you could simply hide these with some css:

```
.logged-in .login-links {

    display: none;

}
```

Where `.login-links` would be the container of the links you mentioned and `.logged-in` the body class.

If you provide a link you'll get a quicker solution.